# Very Simple Javascript Toggle Not Working

Tags: javascript, toggle

I am trying to create a simple toggle class using javascript but there is an issue with my code. Can someone let me know what the mistake is? Thanks.

HTML:

```
<div id="buttonOne">CLick Here One</div>
   <div id="carouselOne">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi incidunt minus laudantium, tempora fuga expedita odit esse fugiat, quas vel debitis, quae dolorem dolores neque labore. Cumque placeat assumenda, mollitia!</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#carouselOne {
    display: none;
}

#buttonOne {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.toggleHideShow {
    display:block;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var btnOne = document.getElementById("buttonOne");

function functionOne() {
    var carOne = document.getElementById("carouselOne");
    if ( carOne.className == "" ) {
        carOne.className = "toggleHideShow";
    }else {
        carOne.className = "";
    }
}
btnOne.addEventListener("click", functionOne);
```

Comment: Is the click event bound when the DOM is ready?

Comment: yes the event is bound

Comment: use jquery instead to avoid stuck with this kind of problems

Comment: `==` is for comparison, `=` for assignment!

Comment: Yea with jQuery its simple but i am trying to learn with raw Javascript.

Comment: Create a snippet using `<>` button in editor.

Comment: You change this question a couple of times and make new mistakes. Try to wait for the answer. Now your example is not working because `#` is more important than `.`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var btnOne = document.getElementById("buttonOne");

function functionOne() {
  var carOne = document.getElementById("carouselOne");

  carOne.classList.toggle('hidden');
}

btnOne.addEventListener("click", functionOne);
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonOne">CLick Here One</div>

<div id="carouselOne">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi incidunt minus laudantium, tempora fuga expedita odit esse fugiat, quas vel debitis, quae dolorem dolores neque labore. Cumque placeat assumenda, mollitia!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: *"try this"* isn't a proper  explanation

Answer (score 1):

Change css line

```
.toggleHideShow {
```

to

```
#carouselOne.toggleHideShow {
```

And this will work

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: @mplungjan Yes I tried

Comment: Why not show it working? Or at least explain why